# How to read JSON in electron when sending script from express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, electron

How can I read JSON that's in my local electron files in a script that's sent by express server.

I want to send my local JSON to my express server because I have local data that I need on a server.

I'll be delighted to get any answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn more about "fs"'s method to read and write JSON data locally on your computer: [here](https://w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_filesystem.asp)

To send your JSON data to the express server, you need to modify a few things on the express server to receive and write the data. Then use `axios or fetch` to do it

Comment: the problem is that when i include my normal read script in the file it crashes

Comment: To read a JSON file: `JSON.parse(path)`
To write it, you must convert it to string: `JSON.stringify(variable)`